# Need Help implementing FileNameFilter java

Tags: java, swing, tree, jtree

I want to create an application which will show files in a directory whose name starts with a string i.e. some date. now i am able to all the FileNameFilter explicitly but since TreeModel is  an interface i can't change anything. at the function `getChild(Object parent , int index)` I am getting ArrayOutofBoundException because the array gets empty when i access it because the filter removes the file name from the list. I am stuck here with no possible solution. I have tried many more things.

I am using swing outline here.

Code which calls TreeModel :

```
FileTreeModel treeMdl = new FileTreeModel(f);
treeMdl.setDate(strDate);
mdl = DefaultOutlineModel.createOutlineModel(treeMdl, new FileRowModel(), true);
outline.setRenderDataProvider(new RenderData());
outline.setModel(mdl);
```

Class FileTreeModel:

```
public class FileTreeModel implements TreeModel {

private String date;
private File root;

public FileTreeModel(File root) {
    this.root = root;
}

@Override
public void addTreeModelListener(javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener l) {

}

@Override
public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
    File f = (File) parent;
    File[] listFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().startsWith(date);
        }
    });
    return listFiles[index];
}

public void setDate(String Date) {
    date = Date;
}

public Object getChild1(Object parent, int index, String dir, String date) throws IOException {
    File f = (File) parent;
    File[] listFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().startsWith(date);
        }
    });

    return listFiles[index].getName();
}

@Override
public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
    File f = (File) parent;
    if (!f.isDirectory()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return f.list().length;
    }
}

@Override
public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
    File par = (File) parent;
    File ch = (File) child;
    return Arrays.asList(par.listFiles()).indexOf(ch);
}

@Override
public Object getRoot() {
    return root;
}

@Override
public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
    File f = (File) node;
    return !f.isDirectory();
}

@Override
public void removeTreeModelListener(javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener l) {

}

@Override
public void valueForPathChanged(javax.swing.tree.TreePath path, Object newValue) {
    //do nothing
}
}
```

Here I have also created a function `getChild1()` which returns me the list of files correctly how i want but i cant get the same result in Interface as the index parameter can't be controlled.

Edit:

Output:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at sr.view.FileTreeModel.getChild(FileTreeModel.java:57)
at org.netbeans.swing.outline.DefaultOutlineModel.getChild(DefaultOutlineModel.java:231)
at javax.swing.tree.FixedHeightLayoutCache$SearchInfo.getPath(FixedHeightLayoutCache.java:1467)
at javax.swing.tree.FixedHeightLayoutCache.getPathForRow(FixedHeightLayoutCache.java:211)
at org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline.sortAndFilter(Outline.java:511)
at org.netbeans.swing.etable.ETable.convertRowIndexToModel(ETable.java:1599)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2719)
at org.netbeans.swing.etable.ETable.getValueAt(ETable.java:772)
```

Comment: In your `getChild1()` you don't use the parameter `dir` and you already have the date in the model. So what's the difference to `getChild()`? Besides that, you might want to consider wrapping the files in some class that represents the node and either uses `toString()` to display the filename or you use a custom renderer for your nodes.

Comment: @Thomas  `getChild()`  is the function used by the swing outline model since it is an interface. `getChild1()` was created only for testing purpose and it was successful. But i cant implement filter in `getChild()`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: My question was: what's the problem with implementing `getChild()` like you implemented `getChild1()`? As I said the different signature should not be a problem since you don't use `dir` anyway and can get `date` from the model itself. What's left is the exact same signature as `getChild()` has (except the throws declaration but that can be solved by wrapping the exception in a `RuntimeException`).

Comment: @Thomas ok. so the problem is i get an `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception because the file passed contains every file and directory but as soon as the filter is applied the list is decreased also the index should be decreased but the index doesn't decrease corresponding to the `FileNameFilter`

Comment: Your getChildCOunt() method return the total number of files in the directory. But your getChild() method filters the list of files. You need to be consistent. Either your tree shows all the files, and all the methods should deal with the complete list of files, or it shows a filtered list, and all the methods should deal with the filtered list.

Comment: I cannot pass a list of files so how can I implement this with the filter?

Answer (score 0):

There was no possible way to make this work so I created a list of filtered files which I wanted to display and added them to JTree. In the end a listener was added to print only .pdf files when clicked else will do nothing.

If anyone want that solution i'll paste here a gist link.

Thanks!